# Squid is not caching

Tags: squid

I have been trying to install Squid version 3.1.20 on Ubuntu version 12.10 by entering `sudo apt-get install squid`, but the problem is the squid I installed it is not caching. I tried to browse to the same websites many times it keep showing me `TCP_MISS` all the times. As I understand it should show `TCP_HIT`.
The configuration is very simple. I just added the below statements into the squid configuration file.

```
acl allow_network src 172.16.0.0/16  

http_access allow allow_network
```

Please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

First off, Squid 3 is installed by:

`sudo apt-get install squid3`

Then, you have to add your acl, which you have done, good.

Then you need to create your cache_dirs by running:

`sudo squid3 -z`

Then you need to start the service:

`sudo service squid3 start`

After that, you might need to tweek your config a bitty, look at: allow_cache and always_direct, you really don't want the latter! Have a read of this: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#Can_I_make_Squid_proxy_only.2C_without_caching_anything.3F for what NOT to do. I tend to use `cache allow all`